# Loop function advice

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently doing a course on the fundamentals of python and I have a question regarding the below loop function:

```
x = 0
for index in range(5, 10):
    x = x + 10
    print("The value of X is {}".format(x))
```

When I print it I get the following result:

```
The value of X is 10
The value of X is 20
The value of X is 30
The value of X is 40
The value of X is 50
```

This is where I get confused, I was expecting a result like:

```
The value of X is 60
The value of X is 70
The value of X is 80
The value of X is 90
The value of X is 100
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: x starts out at 0, then <br/>

x = x + 10   (10 = 0 + 10), now x = 10, then <br/>

x = x + 10   (20 = 10 + 10), now x = 20..... <br/>

why were you expecting 60 - 100? there is no multiplication, and `index` isn't used in any calculation

Comment: You are not even using `index`, is that normal ?

Comment: I am aware that index has no value, I am doing the Python fundamentals at the moment and index is merely a place holder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the code line by line:

- First, you initialize the variable x to the value 0.
- Then you set up a loop which will run five times.
- You add 10 to the original value of x, and set that new value to x
- You print the value of x.
- Repeat 5 times.

x starts at 0, then you add 10, then 10 again, and so on, until the final value is 50. Does that make sense?

To produce the output you are expecting, this is a loop you could use:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> for index in range(6, 11):
...   x = index * 10
...   print("The value of X is {}".format(x))

The value of X is 60
The value of X is 70
The value of X is 80
The value of X is 90
The value of X is 100
```

Comment: Thanks Ethan, but as I stated to Daniel in the range I set the start int to 5 and the stop int to 10. Thus shouldn't the operation start count from 50 and stopping when reaching 100?

Comment: `range(5, 10)` will produce an array like this: `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` there are 5 numbers in that array, so that's how many times your loop will run. The for loop iterates over the array once for each array element. These numbers have nothing to do with the value of x.

Comment: Thank you very much... this is where I was getting confused. Now I understand, I was expecting it to start from 50 and move to 100.

Answer (score 1):

What your function effectively does is to call

```
x = x + 10
```

five times. Since it is initialized with `x = 0`, the output makes sense to me.

The `index` variable in the loop is not used at all. The following loops would be equivalent:

```
for _ in range(5, 10):
    ...

for i in range(0, 5):
    ...
```

In your case, it is only about repeating a certain operation 5 times.

If you wanted to have an output as described in the questions, you would need to modify the loop as follows:

```
x = 10

for i in range(5, 10):
    # This loop will be performed for values
    # of i of [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], so it includes
    # the first value (5) and excludes that last
    # one (10)

    print(x * i)

>> 50
>> 60
>> 70
>> 80
>> 90
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, in the range I set the start int to 5 and the stop to 10. So if I understand correctly, shouldn't it start at 50 print until it reaches 100

Comment: The loop only updates the value of `index`, which you do not use at all. Hence it doesn't matter if it ranges from 0 to 5, from 5 to 10, or from 1019 to 1024. It's only about executing the code _within_ the loop five times, which increase your value of x from 0 to 10 to 20 to 30 etc.

Comment: Thanks that sums it up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is value of x, index at each loop iteration

```
   Iteration 1. x = 10 + 0 , index = 5 
   Iteration 2. x = 10 + 10 , index = 6 
   Iteration 3. x = 10 + 20 , index = 7 
   Iteration 4. x = 10 + 30 , index = 8 
   Iteration 5. x = 10 + 40 , index = 9
```

Thats how your loop will execute

Comment: Thanks for your response vRathee.

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of `x` is set to `0` and in each iteration of the loop you're adding 10 to it. That's why you get these values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanted it something like this.

```
x = 0
for index in range(6,11):
    x = index*10
    print("The value of X is {}".format(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response